# log4net performance: should i check log level before trying to log?

Tags: c#, log4net

Would you expect better performance from A) or B) below if log level in the log4net config is set to Info level? Will _log.Debug on its own execute more code and take longer?

A)

```
if(_log.IsDebugEnabled)
  _log.Debug("some message");
```

B)

```
_log.Debug("some message");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, I'd use B.

However, if constructing the log message (the argument to `log.Debug`) may take a while - involving significant string concatenation, for example - then I would go for A. It will end up performing the same test twice in the "yes, log it" case, but it won't need to construct the log message in the "no, don't log it" case.

Answer (score 4):

I would choose option B unless the log message itself takes a long time to construct. The performance gain for the usual case is negligible or doesn't even exist. Internally, log4net does the same check so you won't change anything by doing it yourself.

But as I said, option A may be a good idea in a situation like this:

```
if (_log.IsDebugEnabled())
{
    var message = createComplicatedLogMessageThatTakesALotOfTime();
    _log.Debug(message);
}
```

For all other cases, it just adds three more lines for every message you log which just isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Previous analysis revealed that Log4Net's `IsXXXEnabled` implementation isn't the fastest as it is calling several other methods. NLog's version does a volatile read, so it's much faster, but really, if your bottleneck lies in `IsXXXEnabled` you are already doing low-latency stuff and might end-up cooking your own dedicated logging.

Comment: could you be more specific about your "previous analysis" ?

Comment: Grabbing a decompiler and stepping through Log4Net's IsXXX enabled - you jump through many virtual method calls.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the first option is slightly more performant I would't worry so much.

However if you do something like this:

```
_log.Debug(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}...", param1, param2, param3));
```

then there is a strong case for checking _log.IsDebugEnabled before.

Answer (score 0):

Option A is better, because:

You probably don't know what is wrapped behind the Debug() method. Is it a local wrapper that someone added to process extra logic into before passing to log4net's Debug() call? What is log4net doing in that method? You might be using the source for log4net to build your assembly, has another team member changed it? Ok, so you personally audited the code, and it is very fast and you are using the assembly from Nuget, so you know nobody on your team has changed it. What about tomorrow when a new version of log4net drops? How do you know that someone working on a log4net bug hasn't introduced some logging code that melts your server in all your tight loops? Is the next intern who copies your code and makes changes to it as knowledgeable as you are and thinking of how making verbose complex log calls can be more costly than expected? Also, keep in mind that differing appenders might have differing log costs. What happens if someone changes out a lightweight fast async appender for a slower synchronous one?

Bottom line: Code defensively. This is a bool check that is really simple and cheap, and it could prevent some unexpected and tricky performance problems at scale and under load. Are you ever going to look at this check and say, 'I really regret writing that'? Unlikely.

Comment: For debug this may be the case but for other methods like log() and after looking at hundreds of lines of if statements checking, then it's starting to bloat the code and be meaningless.